# Wrong likes number via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

There is couple ways to get number of page likes in graph api, and the most simple way is just get JSON response via this url, for instance:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://cnn.com/
```

However, that method returns wrong number of likes:

```
{
   "id": "http://cnn.com/",
   "shares": 138855,
   "comments": 39
}
```

CNN page has facebook widget that shows actual number of likes (1.4 million):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLeXT.png

Is there a way to get likes number from API exactly the same as in facebook like widget on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your view of what these numbers are talking about is wrong:

The number 1.4 million corresponds the number of people who liked the **page** [CNN International](https://www.facebook.com/cnninternational?fref=ts).

The query `http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://cnn.com/` looks for the number of times the [Open Graph object at cnn.com](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=cnn.com) has been shared.

> Is there a way to get likes number from API exactly the same as in
>   facebook like widget on the page?

There's always a possiblity of lag. If you want absolute real-time you should implement a [javascript event listener on the edge.create](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) and track it yourself. Personally, I don't need things in definite real-time, so I prefer using FQL with the [link_stat](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat) table.